# SSH connection to GCP VM Instance is unstable

Tags: ssh

I am a novice GCP user, I am trying to run a Deep Learning Model on "GCP Deep Learning VM". The model can take up to 8-9 days to run. But the ssh connection is not stable and does not respond after a few(5-8) hours and the model stops executing.

How to stabilize the SSH connection and complete the model training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For long running tasks like this it is recommended to not run them directly inside your SSH session at all.

Applications like [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen), [tmux](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) and [byobu](https://linux.die.net/man/1/byobu) allow you to resume a session with all your tasks running, even when nobody is connected via SSH.